# Why was my question closed as exact duplicate?

Tags: support, closed-questions

[I am talking about this question.](https://superuser.com/questions/487711/how-to-hide-desktop-ini-files-without-hiding-other-hidden-files-folders#comment579611_487711)

I am not trying to argue to have it reopened or anything, I would just like to know how it's an exact duplicate of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/139663/show-hide-hidden-files-on-demand-in-windows) when the other question is about showing and hiding all hidden files in windows on command, when mine was about showing everything all of the time, *execpt* desktop.ini files.

Can someone please explain to me how they are exact duplicates when they have nothing in common except that they have *something* to do with hidden files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can someone please explain to me how they are exact duplicates when they have nothing in common except that they have something to do with hidden files?

They aren't. I've examined both questions – they have something in common, but yours is way more specific. I believe the reason it was suggested as a duplicate was:

> […] It'd probably be easier to just rig up a system-wide toggle for ALL hidden/system files and just use it as needed, vs. trying to hide files with a specific filename — [*techie007*](https://superuser.com/questions/487711/how-to-hide-desktop-ini-files-without-hiding-other-hidden-files-folders#comment579608_487711)

So, an assumption was made about the possible solution to your problem, which led to the duplicate. This might be helpful in some cases where the OP phrased their problem wrong, i.e. just [asked about their attempted solution rather than the actual issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

In your case I believe it's fine to stay as a separate question though. Reopened.